# SQL Server : execution plan explanation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this execution plan, but I have just a slight guess what's happening here. I think the plan divide my query to 2 interval, which are inner joined, but I have no clue what is the upper row means starting with the Merge interval.

[My plan on Brentozar](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HJG84-Gw_)

My query is:

```
select Price, ID 
from product 
where price <> 800
```

`ID` is my primary key, `Price` has index

Thank you in advance

[image]

Comment: You should post your plan to https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ - makes it much easier for everyone to see what it is and maybe be able to help !

Comment: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HJG84-Gw_ here is the plan. Sorry for not including it, I have just started using sql-server and didn't know such sites exists.

Comment: `Merge inteval` is typically used to remove duplicated predicates in a query and to find possible overlapping intervals to optimize the predicates to avoid repeatedly scanning the same data.

Comment: Looks like `800` has been auto-parameterized, but because it's an `int` it needs to convert to `float` calculate start and end index lookups to pass through to the Seek. This is done via the top half of the plan, and does not itself take a long time, though the result can affect the Seek quite drastically. The two Compute Scalars are the start and end points, these are concatenated and if necessary merged (in this case we know they are different). What happens if you use `where price <> 800.0`

Comment: @Charlieface -  the datatype of `800.0` is `numeric(4,1)` - so that would still be mismatched. `8e2` would be one way of expressing that as a `float` literal - I'd expect all that apparatus to disappear and just a single index seek operator with multiple seek conditions in that case though

Comment: Having actually tested it now `create table product(ID int primary key, Price float INDEX IX)` and then `select * from product where Price <> 800.0` it starts off auto parameterised with a `numeric(4,1)` parameter but then it bails out of the auto parameterisation and the final plan has the literal values converted to `float` at compile time rather than parameter references (i.e. references `8.0000000000000000e+002`  directly)

Comment: Using an actual float literal is not really an improvement here though. Just get a scan with a predicate and no seek at all. Maybe down to stats on my empty table or maybe something to do with float datatype

Comment: Perhaps `where price <> cast(800 as float(53))` or `where price <> 8e2` as suggested by @MartinSmith

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This apparatus is used for ["dynamic seeks"](https://www.sql.kiwi/2012/01/dynamic-seeks-and-hidden-implicit-conversions.html) in SQL Server. Often you will see this due to mismatched datatypes.

In your case the literal `800` is auto parameterised to an `int` parameter and the plan later has a `CONVERT_IMPLICIT(float(53),[@1],0)` to convert it to the datatype of the `price` column. I replace this with `800e0` below (one way of declaring that value as a float literal)

(sidenote: price should not be float - you should use a precise datatype such as `decimal`)

[image]

- Node 6 outputs a single row with no columns. The compute scalar in
  Node 5 adds three columns to the row with values `(NULL, 800e0, 10)`
- Node 8 outputs a single row with no columns. The compute scalar in
  Node 7 adds three columns to the row with values `(800e0, NULL, 6)`
- Node 4 is a concatenation operator that `UNION ALL`s the above two rows together. The resultant columns are aliased as `(Expr1009, Expr1010, Expr1011)` - these correspond to `(startOfRange, endOfRange, Flags)` - `NULL` here [means "unbounded"](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14789/can-you-explain-this-execution-plan/14812#comment22402_14812)
- Nodes 3,2 and 1 are concerned with ordering the ranges so that overlapping ones can be collapsed down and have no effect in this case.
- Node 9 is an index seek that is executed twice (for the two rows on the outside of the join). This has a seek predicate of `Price > Expr1009 AND Price < Expr1010` - i.e. `Price > startOfRange AND Price < endOfRange`. So it is called for range `(NULL, 800)` and range `(800, NULL)`

So the net effect of all this is that the `<> 800` predicate gets converted to two index seeks. One on `< 800` and the other on `>800`